# Display all items from table to listbox if UserID match

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new in asp .net and I'm trying to display all user tasks from the Tasks table into ListBox. I connected tables tblUsers and Tasks with foreign key UserID.I'm trying to compare UserID of the users who is logged in with UserID from tasks in an if statement but I don't know how.
Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-PIERKI5\SQLEXPRESS;initial Catalog=LoginDb;integrated Security=True;");
    string com = "Select UserID, taskName from Tasks";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "Tables");
    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
    DataRow tempRow = null;

    if(Session["UserID"] == )
    {
        foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)

        {

            tempRow = tempRow_Variable;

            TasksListBox.Items.Add((tempRow["taskName"].ToString()));

        }
    }
    
}
```

LOGIN PAGE, code for login button

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-PIERKI5\SQLEXPRESS;initial Catalog=LoginDb;integrated Security=True;");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserName= '"+txtName.Text+"' AND Password= '"+txtPassword.Text+"' AND Usertype= '"+ DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0) //admin
        {
            Session["username"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("Default_admin.aspx");
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1) //user
        {
            Session["username"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("Default_user.aspx");
        }
    }
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QOYo.png)

Comment: Why not filter on your query by using a `WHERE UserId = {youruserid}`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new in this can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: You could filter down to records of the current user by adding a `WHERE` clause to your SQL. Please read more about it: [sql-where-clause](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-where-clause/)

Comment: How do I get current UserID?

Comment: It looks like from your example that you are storing it in `Session` -> `Session["UserID"]`

Comment: That's UserID from Tasks. How do I compare this with the current user UserID. How do I get this UserID?

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net Forms application? If so, see this post: [get-id-of-current-logged-in-user-in-asp-net-web-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385299/get-id-of-current-logged-in-user-in-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: Asp.Net Empty web site. It's a school assignment and we can't use identity

Comment: Then what are you using? How does a person enter the site? Is it using `Windows Authentication`? Is it using any type of authentication at all? Or are you just letting anyone onto the website?

Comment: I added the code for login button

Comment: Since you are using `SELECT *` in your login, you should have an `id` column being returned if they successfully login (are an authorized user), so you could set the `id` into `Session` when they successfully login and use it in your other piece of code where you get the tasks.

Comment: Ok, I create a variable in login form and saved UserID in a variable, but how can I now reach this variable from another page?

Comment: Yikes, this looks crazy vulnerable to SQL injection issues. It's also **NEVER** okay to just store a password in the database. Those are the two things that are too important to do wrong **even on learning and proof-of-concept projects**.

Answer (score 0):

well, if we can assume that session() already does have the user id?

Then you want to do this:

first up, setup the connection string global to the applcation. Be it desktop, or web, you can use the setting pages. (the settings are automatic moved to web config for you).

So, use settings pages to setup your connection. Not only does this put/place the connection string in ONE place, but also means that you don't have to place that connection string in your code - nor type it over and over.

So, Project-> Properties. Then settings tab

this:

[image]

So, add your connection string to above. and REALLY nice is you get to use the connection string builder:

So, lets add MYTEST

[image]

Then click on that [...], and we get the standard connection builder.

[image]

And note even the test connection button above.

Ok, so, now we simple filter and load the table based on user id.

This code:

On that 2nd page, then say this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();

    }
    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MYTEST))
        {
            string strSQL 
                = "SELECT taskName FROM Tasks WHERE UserID = @ID ORDER BY taskName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)(Session["UserID"]);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                ListBox1.DataSource = rstData;
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, on your logon page, I did not see you save/store/set the session for UserID, and we are assuming that been done before we get to this 2nd page.

So we don't need some for each for filling out the listbox - we can use that data table as the source to the ListBox.

## Edit: - what kind of project is this

There are a BOATLOAD choice of projects - especially given how long VS has been around, and the number of technology changes over the years.

So, if you create a blank asp.net web site, you not have settings.

[image]

In above, the first 3 on the left - 3 choices!

So, a asp.net web site is NOT the same as a asp.net web site applcation!!!

So, if you create a empty web site, the it not a "applcation", and you not see/have the settings page.

But, lets create a empty web site applcation, like this:

[image]

then you get this:

(project name etc, and when you hit create, you get this paneal next:

[image]

So, above is a empty asp.net web site application.

And in above, I probably should un-check the https setting. (not required).

so, in addition to all teh above choices?

Then you have .net core choices.

And then you have MVC choices. So, BIG product, BIG choices, and it can be difficult to figure out what and which one to choose.

But, the "big" differance here is applcation vs not application. The applcation model and web site work quite much the same, but I perfer and use "applcation". Its much the same, but you have a whole lot better compile time and class resolution when using a web site.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find a Properties :(

Comment: So, Project-> Properties. Then settings tab
you mean that in visual studio right? Because the is no properties under project  :/

Comment: yes - see my edit above - I show how to create different kinds of projects. - you not see properties page if you create JUST a web site as opposed to a web site applcation. see the edit I added to this post.

Comment: Thank you for your long answer but sadly this is a school assignment and we have to use master pages and I see that in this option this is not possible

Comment: Is there any way how to do this in ASP.NET Empty Website (C#)?

Comment: You are most free to use master pages. In fact if you are using master pages, then I bet without question your not using a empty web site, since that wouldn't create any master pages for you? Unless you're supposed to create the master page from scratch? I would assume you create a web site with the master page already wired up for you? I mean you can hand type in the db connection if you wish as you have - but that's not in general workable to re type connection over and over in code.  posted code is fine if you don't use properties as my example did - replace properties with your connection

Comment: Choice and use of master pages is not related to using settings for connections